Kurtosis of the Rice distribution
The Rice distribution $X$ (over $\mathbb{R}$) is the magnitude of $\vec{X}$, where $\vec X$ is a shifted 2D normal distribution $\vec{N}$ (over $\mathbb{R}^2$).
Say the 2D normal distribution has standard deviation $\sigma$ in each component, and is shifted by $\vec{\Lambda} = (\Lambda, 0)^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
I now want to calculate the fourth-order moment of $X$.
Since $|\vec v|^4 = \vec v^4$, I can do this by calculating the expected value of $\vec X^4$ directly.
$$
\begin{align*} 
\langle X^4 \rangle = \langle \vec X^4 \rangle  &= \langle (\vec \Lambda + \vec N)^4\rangle \\
&= \langle \vec \Lambda^4 + 4 \vec \Lambda^3 \vec N + 6 \vec \Lambda^2 \vec  N^2 + 4\vec \Lambda \vec N^3 + \vec N^4\rangle \\
&= \Lambda^4 + 4 \Lambda^2 \langle \vec \Lambda \vec N\rangle + 6 \Lambda^2 \langle \vec N^2\rangle + 4 \langle \vec \Lambda  \vec N^3\rangle + \langle \vec N^4\rangle \\
&= \Lambda^4 + 0 + 6 \Lambda^2 2 \sigma^2 + 0 + 8 \sigma^4 \\
&= \Lambda^4 + 12 \Lambda^2 \sigma^2+ 8 \sigma^4
\end{align*}
$$
where I have used the following moments of a circularly symmetric central normal distribution:
$$
\begin{align*} 
\langle \vec N\rangle &= \vec{0} &
\langle \vec N^2\rangle &= 2\sigma^2 &
\langle \vec N^3\rangle &= \vec{0} &
\langle \vec N^4\rangle &= 8\sigma^2
\end{align*}
$$
And the fact that the constant vector $\vec\Lambda$ can be pulled out of the expectation value.
However, the fourth moment is actually
$$ \langle \vec X^4 \rangle  = \Lambda^4 + 8 \Lambda^2 \sigma^2+ 8 \sigma^4 \neq \Lambda^4 + \mathbf{12} \Lambda^2 \sigma^2+ 8 \sigma^4$$
How?
I do not get how I would obtain a factor of 8 from the calculation above.

Because your characterization of the Rice distribution is incorrect (it is the distribution of the magnitude of a circularly symmetric bivariate Normal variable), please clarify what distribution you intend $X$ to have.

I do really want $X$ to be Rice distributed.
And I was calculating it like this since $\langle X^4\rangle = \langle |X|^4\rangle$

$N$ is two dimensional while $X$ is scalar and it is unclear what you intend $\Lambda$ to be, so it is not obvious to me that all your manipulations are legitimate.  For example if $\langle N\rangle$ means $\langle |N|\rangle$ then it would not be $0$.


$\Lambda$ is a constant 2D vector $(\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2)^T$ Its direction should not matter as $\langle N^4\rangle$ only depends on its length.
$\langle N\rangle$ is not equal to $\langle |N|\rangle$. $N$ is a 2D normal distribution and as such has a PDF(x,y) with expected value $(0,0)^T$


I have added vector arrows to all 2D vectors to make it clearer

The Rice distribution, as @Henry points out, is a scalar distribution, whereas your description and language continue to characterize it as vector-valued.  We are concerned that you haven't described your problem in a way that will be interpreted as you intend.

I think I finally understood what you were trying to say. Yes, the rice distribution is scalar. Since I want to calculate an even-order moment,  I do not need to take the intermediary step of taking the magnitudes of everything and am calculating with the  equivalent 2D distribution directly. I have updated my question for the final time, hopefully.

Your notation might be a principal source of confusion.  For instance, what do you mean by "$|\vec v|^4 = \vec v^4$" and how do you justify that??  I tried to interpret the right hand side as the sum of fourth powers of the components of a vector $v,$ but there's no way I can justify equating that with any reasonable interpretation of the left hand side.

For me, $\vec{v}^4 = \vec{v}\cdot (\vec{v}\cdot (\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})) = \vec{v}\cdot (\vec{v}\cdot |\vec{v}|^2) = |\vec{v}|^2 \cdot (\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v} ) = |\vec{v}|^2 \cdot |\vec{v}|^2 =  |\vec{v}|^4 $ where $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} =  |\vec{v}|^2$ is the dot product.

Okay--but be aware that is nonstandard and likely to be misinterpreted.  I suspect the most popular interpretation would be the one I suggested.

Ok, I figured it out in the meantime.
The main cause is that I have been too lax with rearranging the vector products.
Let $A, B$ be 2D vectors with magnitude $a, b$ and dot product $A\cdot B = c^2$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
(A+B)^4 &= (A+B)(A+B)(A+B)(A+B) \\
&= (A+B)(A+B)(a^2 + 2 c^2 + b^2) \\
&= (A+B)((A+B)a^2 + (A+B)2 c^2 + (A+B)b^2) \\
&= (a^2 + 2 c^2 + b^2)a^2 + (a^2 + 2 c^2 + b^2)2 c^2 + (a^2 + 2 c^2 + b^2)b^2 \\ 
&= a⁴ + 2 a²c² + a²b² + 2a²c² + 4c⁴ + 2c²b² + a²b² +2c²b² + b⁴ \\
&= (a⁴) + (4a²c²) + (2 a²b² + 4 c⁴) + (4c²b²) + b⁴ 
\end{align}
$$
Which is to say that the central term in my question does not actually evaluate to $6 \Lambda^2 \langle \vec N^2 \rangle$, but to
$2 \Lambda^2 \langle \vec N^2 \rangle + 4 \langle (\vec \Lambda \vec N)^2 \rangle$, where if one inserts the 1D and 2D normal moments
$$\langle \vec N^2 \rangle = 2\sigma^2, \qquad \langle (\vec e_1 \vec N)^2 \rangle = \langle N_1^2 \rangle = \sigma^2$$
(where $N_1$ is the first component of the 2D $\vec N$)
then it actually results in the correct answer
$$2 \Lambda^2 \langle \vec N^2 \rangle + 4 \langle (\vec \Lambda \vec N)^2 \rangle = 2 \Lambda^2 2 \sigma^2 + 4 \Lambda^2 \sigma^2 = \mathbf{8} \Lambda^2 \sigma^2$$.
